# Why can I not have `else` (from if / else) with python generator expressions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, generator-expression

I have the following code, which works fine:

```
incl_list = ['A']
my_list = [{'A': 1, 'B': 'world'}, {'A': 4, 'B': 'hello'}]
result = '\n'.join(','.join(f'{key}={value}' for key, value in record.items() if key in incl_list) for record in my_list)
```

The result yields:

```
'A=1\nA=4'
```

My question is why can I not add an `else` statement, like so:

```
result = '\n'.join(','.join(f'{key}={value}' for key, value in record.items() if key in incl_list) else 'ignore' for record in my_list)
```

similar to list-comprehension?

The error I get is:

```
 File "<ipython-input-276-201c8f88ac13>", line 1
    result = '\n'.join(','.join(f'{key}={value}' for key, value in record.items() if key in incl_list else 'ignore') for record in my_list)
                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Any errors that occur?

Comment: You can use `a if b else c for d in e`, not whatever you were trying to do.

Comment: @zixuan I updated it now.

Comment: @khelwood I suggest you check it carefully. This is exactly what I try to do and it does not seem to work. with the `else` but works only with the `if`

Comment: @Newskooler I suggest *you* check it carefully. That is not what you are doing.

Comment: @khelwood You are right indeed. Apologies for my confusion. With so many nestings it's hard to keep track sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` statement needs to go together with an `if` statement, when using inside a comprehension, thus you could modify your code like so to make it work

```py
result = '\n'.join(','.join(f'{key}={value}' if key in incl_list else 'ignore' for key, value in record.items()) for record in my_list)
```